# Centering text in bigdelim environment

Tags: longtable, bigdelim

I need some quick help figuring out how to center text in a `longtable` where I use `bigdelim/multirow`.

An MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%---------- Page Style ----------
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
%------------ Tables ------------
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}                                          % for curly braces in tables
\usepackage{booktabs}                                                   % redefines thickness of lines for table frames
%-------- Chemistry -------------
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

%--------------- END OF PREAMBLE ---------------------%

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{} l c c c c @{}}
\caption[]{Constants and parameters (modern-day standards).} \\

\hline \addlinespace
Parameter & Definition & Value & Units & Ref \\ \midrule
$R$ & ideal gas law constant & 8.314 & $m^3$Pa/Kmol & \\
$\text{Pa}_\text{atm}$ & pascals per atmosphere & $1.023\times10^5$& Pa & \\
$\kappa_\text{0,O2}$ & \rdelim\}{5}{250pt}[ Henry's Law constants at $T_0$ ]  \ldelim\{{5}{35pt}[] & $1.2\times10^{-5}$ & mol/m$^{3}$Pa & S15\\ 
$\kappa_\text{0,CO2}$ &    & $3.3\times10^{-4}$ & mol/m$^{3}$Pa & S15\\ 
$\kappa_\text{0,CH4}$ &    & $1.4\times10^{-5}$ & mol/m$^{3}$Pa & S15\\ 
$\kappa_\text{0,N2}$  &    & $6.4\times10^{-6}$ & mol/m$^{3}$Pa & S15\\ 
$\kappa_\text{0,NH3}$ &    & $5.9\times10^{-1}$ & mol/m$^{3}$Pa & S15\\  
$D_\text{O2}$ & \rdelim\}{5}{250pt}[ Diffusion constants ]  \ldelim\{{5}{22pt}[]& $1.78\times10^{-5}$ &  cm/s & CRC\\ 
$D_\text{CO2}$ &    & $1.45\times10^{-5}$ & cm/s & CRC\\ 
$D_\text{CH4}$ &    & $1.55\times10^{-5}$ & cm/s & CRC\\ 
$D_\text{N2}$ &     & $2\times10^{-5}$ & cm/s & CRC\\ 
$D_\text{NH3}$ &    & $1.5\times10^{-5}$ & cm/s & CRC\\
$K_\text{O,rm}$ & half-saturation uptake values for \ce{O2} in remineralization & $12\times10^{-6}$ & mol/L & L17\\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
```

For instance, I want the text "Henry's Law constants" to be centered between the two curly braces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- for { is introduced new column `r`
- for chemistry formulae is strict used macro `\ce{...}` (even in subscripts)
- for units are used `siunitx` package
- text in the second column is not centered, to my taste left align is nicer

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
%---------- Page Style ----------
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
%------------ Tables ------------
%\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bigdelim}                                          % for curly braces in tables
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable, multirow}                                                   % redefines thickness of lines for table frames
%-------- Chemistry -------------
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
 
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{} >{$}l<{$} p{150pt} r @{\hspace{-2em}} S s[per-mode=symbol, 
                                                     table-unit-alignment=left] l @{}}
    \caption[]{Constants and parameters (modern-day standards).} \\
    \toprule
Parameter & Definition &  & {Value} & {Units} & Ref \\ 
    \midrule
R                   & ideal gas law constant 
                        &   & 8.314     & \cubic\metre\pascal\per\kilo\mole &       \\
\text{Pa}_\text{atm}& pascals per atmosphere    
                        &   & 1.023e5   & Pa                                &       \\
    \addlinespace
\kappa_{\ce{0,O2}}  & \rdelim\}{5}{150pt}[ Henry's Law constants at $T_0$]
                        & \ldelim\{{5}{0pt}[] 
                            & 1.2e-5    & \mole\cubic\metre\pascal          & S15   \\
\kappa_{\ce{0,CO2}} &   &   & 3.3e-4    & \mole\cubic\metre\pascal          & S15   \\
\kappa_{\ce{0,CH4}} &   &   & 1.4e-5    & \mole\cubic\metre\pascal          & S15   \\
\kappa_{\ce{0,N2}}  &   &   & 6.4e-6    & \mole\cubic\metre\pascal          & S15   \\
\kappa_{\ce{0,NH3}} &   &   & 5.9e-1    & \mole\cubic\metre\pascal          & S15   \\
    \addlinespace
D_{\ce{O2}}         & \rdelim\}{5}{150pt}[ Diffusion constants ]  
                        &   \ldelim\{{5}{0pt}[]
                            & 1.78e-5   & \centi\metre\per\second           & CRC   \\
D_{\ce{CO2}}        &   &   & 1.45e-5   & \centi\metre\per\second           & CRC   \\
D_{\ce{CH4}}        &   &   & 1.55e-5   & \centi\metre\per\second           & CRC   \\
D_{\ce{N2}}         &   &   & 2e-5      & \centi\metre\per\second           & CRC   \\
D_{\ce{NH3}}        &   &   & 1.5e-5    & \centi\metre\per\second           & CRC   \\
    \addlinespace
K_{\ce{O,rm}}       & half-saturation uptake values for \ce{O2} in remineralization 
                        &   & 12e-6     & \centi\metre\per\second           & CRC   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
for vertical and horizontal centered text in the second column a new column is introduce and text is moved to rows midle of curly braces:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
%---------- Page Style ----------
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
%------------ Tables ------------
%\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bigdelim}                                          % for curly braces in tables
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable, multirow}                                                   % redefines thickness of lines for table frames
%-------- Chemistry -------------
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
 
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{} >{$}l<{$} l @{\hspace{-10em}}
                    >{\centering}p{0.3\linewidth} 
                                r @{\hspace{-2em}} S s[per-mode=symbol,
                                                       table-unit-alignment=left] l @{}}
    \caption[]{Constants and parameters (modern-day standards).} \\
    \toprule
Parameter       && Definition    
                        &   & {Value}       & {Units}                       & Ref \\ 
    \midrule
R               && ideal gas law constant 
                        &   & 8.314     & \cubic\metre\pascal\per\kilo\mole &       \\
\text{Pa}_\text{atm}
                && pascals per atmosphere    
                        &   & 1.023e5   & Pa                                &       \\
    \addlinespace
\kappa_{\ce{0,O2}}  
            & \rdelim\}{5}{0pt}[]
                &       & \ldelim\{{5}{0pt}[]
                            & 1.2e-5    & \mole\cubic\metre\pascal          & S15   \\
\kappa_{\ce{0,CO2}} 
                &&   &   & 3.3e-4    & \mole\cubic\metre\pascal          & S15   \\
\kappa_{\ce{0,CH4}} 
                && Henry's Law constants at $T_0$
                    &   & 1.4e-5    & \mole\cubic\metre\pascal          & S15   \\
\kappa_{\ce{0,N2}}  
                &&   &   & 6.4e-6    & \mole\cubic\metre\pascal          & S15   \\
\kappa_{\ce{0,NH3}} 
                &&   &   & 5.9e-1    & \mole\cubic\metre\pascal          & S15   \\
    \addlinespace
D_{\ce{O2}} & \rdelim\}{5}{150pt}[] 
                &   & \ldelim\{{5}{0pt}[]
                        & 1.78e-5   & \centi\metre\per\second           & CRC   \\
D_{\ce{CO2}}    &&  &   & 1.45e-5   & \centi\metre\per\second           & CRC   \\
D_{\ce{CH4}}    && Diffusion constants
                   &   & 1.55e-5   & \centi\metre\per\second           & CRC   \\
D_{\ce{N2}}     &&  &   & 2e-5      & \centi\metre\per\second           & CRC   \\
D_{\ce{NH3}}    &&  &   & 1.5e-5    & \centi\metre\per\second           & CRC   \\
    \addlinespace
K_{\ce{O,rm}}       
            &   & half-saturation uptake values for \ce{O2} in remineralization 
                        &   & 12e-6     & \centi\metre\per\second           & CRC   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
One more solution: without curly braces, but with colored table:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
%---------- Page Style ----------
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
%------------ Tables ------------
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable, multirow}                                                   %-------- Chemistry -------------
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
 
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{>{$}l<{$}
                  >{\centering}p{0.3\linewidth} 
                               S 
                               s[per-mode=symbol,
                                 table-unit-alignment=left] 
                               l}
    \caption[]{Constants and parameters (modern-day standards).} \\
    \toprule
\text{Parameter}   
    & Definition    & {Value}   & {Units}                           & Ref \\ 
    \midrule
R   & ideal gas law constant 
                    & 8.314     & \cubic\metre\pascal\per\kilo\mole &       \\
\text{Pa}_\text{atm}
    & pascals per atmosphere    
                    & 1.023e5   & Pa                                &       \\
    \addlinespace
    \rowcolor{gray!15}
\kappa_{\ce{0,O2}}  
    &               & 1.2e-5    & \mole\cubic\metre\pascal          & S15   \\
    \rowcolor{gray!15}
\kappa_{\ce{0,CO2}} 
    &               & 3.3e-4    & \mole\cubic\metre\pascal          & S15   \\
    \rowcolor{gray!15}
\kappa_{\ce{0,CH4}} 
    &               & 1.4e-5    & \mole\cubic\metre\pascal          & S15   \\
    \rowcolor{gray!15}
\kappa_{\ce{0,N2}}  
    &               & 6.4e-6    & \mole\cubic\metre\pascal          & S15   \\
    \rowcolor{gray!15}
\kappa_{\ce{0,NH3}} 
    & \multirow{-5}{=}{\centering
                      Henry's Law constants at $T_0$}
                     & 5.9e-1    & \mole\cubic\metre\pascal          & S15   \\
    \addlinespace
    \rowcolor{gray!15}
D_{\ce{O2}} 
    &               & 1.78e-5   & \centi\metre\per\second           & CRC   \\
    \rowcolor{gray!15}
D_{\ce{CO2}}        
    &               & 1.45e-5   & \centi\metre\per\second           & CRC   \\
    \rowcolor{gray!15}
D_{\ce{CH4}}        
    &               & 1.55e-5   & \centi\metre\per\second           & CRC   \\
    \rowcolor{gray!15}
D_{\ce{N2}}         
    &               & 2e-5      & \centi\metre\per\second           & CRC   \\
    \rowcolor{gray!15}
D_{\ce{NH3}}        
    & \multirow{-5}{=}{\centering
                      Diffusion constants}
                    & 1.5e-5    & \centi\metre\per\second           & CRC   \\
    \addlinespace
K_{\ce{O,rm}}       & half-saturation uptake values for \ce{O2} in remineralization 
                            & 12e-6     & \centi\metre\per\second           & CRC   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! All of these suggestions are super helpful! I didn't even consider the colored table option...

Answer (score 3):

Here is a different layout suggestion that does not rely on large braces and comparably large amounts of white space in the middle of the table:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ >{$}l<{$} 
                   S[table-format=2.3e-1, table-align-exponent=false] 
                   s[per-mode=symbol,table-unit-alignment=left] 
                   l @{}}
\caption[]{Constants and parameters (modern-day standards).} \\
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Parameter \& Definition} &  {Value} & {Units} & {Ref} \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{ideal gas law constant}\\
\addlinespace
R                   &   8.314    & \cubic\metre\pascal\per\kilo\mole &       \\
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{pascals per atmosphere}\\
\text{Pa}_\text{atm}&   1.023e5  & Pa                                &       \\
    \addlinespace
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{Henry's Law constants at $T_0$}\\
\kappa_{\ce{0,O2}}  &  1.2e-5    & \mole\per\cubic\metre\per\pascal  & S15   \\
\kappa_{\ce{0,CO2}} &  3.3e-4    & \mole\per\cubic\metre\per\pascal  & S15   \\
\kappa_{\ce{0,CH4}} &  1.4e-5    & \mole\per\cubic\metre\per\pascal  & S15   \\
\kappa_{\ce{0,N2}}  &  6.4e-6    & \mole\per\cubic\metre\per\pascal  & S15   \\
\kappa_{\ce{0,NH3}} &  5.9e-1    & \mole\per\cubic\metre\per\pascal  & S15   \\
    \addlinespace
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{Diffusion constants}\\
D_{\ce{O2}}         & 1.78e-5   & \centi\metre\per\second           & CRC   \\
D_{\ce{CO2}}        & 1.45e-5   & \centi\metre\per\second           & CRC   \\
D_{\ce{CH4}}        & 1.55e-5   & \centi\metre\per\second           & CRC   \\
D_{\ce{N2}}         & 2e-5      & \centi\metre\per\second           & CRC   \\
D_{\ce{NH3}}        & 1.5e-5    & \centi\metre\per\second           & CRC   \\
    \addlinespace
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{half-saturation uptake values for \ce{O2} in remineralization}\\
K_{\ce{O,rm}}       & 12e-6     & \centi\metre\per\second           & CRC   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1! far better then use of braces ...

Comment: yes, this is a much better format! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can do that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{book}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{@{} l c c c c @{}}
\toprule
Parameter & Definition & Value & Units & Ref \\ \midrule
$R$ & ideal gas law constant & 8.314 & $m^3$Pa/Kmol & \\
$\text{Pa}_\text{atm}$ & pascals per atmosphere & $1.023\times10^5$& Pa & \\
$\kappa_\text{0,O2}$ & \Block{5-1}{Henry's Law constants at $T_0$}    & $1.2\times10^{-5}$ & mol/m$^{3}$Pa & S15\\ 
$\kappa_\text{0,CO2}$ &    & $3.3\times10^{-4}$ & mol/m$^{3}$Pa & S15\\ 
$\kappa_\text{0,CH4}$ &    & $1.4\times10^{-5}$ & mol/m$^{3}$Pa & S15\\ 
$\kappa_\text{0,N2}$  &    & $6.4\times10^{-6}$ & mol/m$^{3}$Pa & S15\\ 
$\kappa_\text{0,NH3}$ &    & $5.9\times10^{-1}$ & mol/m$^{3}$Pa & S15\\[2pt]
$D_\text{O2}$ & \Block{5-1}{Diffusion constants} & $1.78\times10^{-5}$ &  cm/s & CRC\\ 
$D_\text{CO2}$ &    & $1.45\times10^{-5}$ & cm/s & CRC\\ 
$D_\text{CH4}$ &    & $1.55\times10^{-5}$ & cm/s & CRC\\ 
$D_\text{N2}$ &     & $2\times10^{-5}$ & cm/s & CRC\\ 
$D_\text{NH3}$ &    & $1.5\times10^{-5}$ & cm/s & CRC\\
$K_\text{O,rm}$ & half-saturation uptake values for \ce{O2} in remineralization & $12\times10^{-6}$ & mol/L & L17\\
\bottomrule
\CodeAfter
\SubMatrix{.}{4-1}{8-1}{\}}
\SubMatrix{.}{9-1}{13-1}{\}}
\SubMatrix{\{}{4-3}{8-3}{.}
\SubMatrix{\{}{9-3}{13-3}{.}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need at least the version 5.10 (2021-02-05) of `nicematrix`. If you use Overleaf, you can upload the latest version of the file `nicematrix.sty` in the repertory of your project (we can find that file on the [SVN server](http://https:www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty) of TeXLive).

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]